# copy files from root level project directory into docker image with sbt-docker plugin

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, sbt

Trying to just grab some files from the root level directory of my project (same level as `build.sbt`) and put them into my docker image using the copy instruction from sbt-docker plugin but getting a files not found error. My code looks like this to try and jump out to the main level `val sparkDir = baseDirectory.value / "../spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7"` but keep running into this error:

```
${HOME}/root/submodule/../spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars: no such file or directory
```

How do I instruct sbt docker using sbt dsl to just copy files in the following manner:
`copyRaw(sparkDir + "/jars", "/opt/spark/jars")`